# Matching string in Rust

Tags: string, rust, matching

I'm new to Rust (1.31) and I would like to understand a simple piece of code that does not compile:

```
fn main() {
    s = String::from("foo");
    match s {
        "foo" => {
            println!("Yes");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
        }
    }
}
```

The error associated is :

```
10 |         "foo" => {                                                                                 
   |         ^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
```

After this error, I decided to change the code to :

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("foo");

    match s {
        String::from("foo") => {
            println!("Yes");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
        }
    }
}
```

By doing so, I was hoping to have the correct type, but it is not the case :

```
10 |         String::from("foo") => {                                                                   
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a tuple variant or struct
```

I am quite puzzled with this message from the compiler, at the end I managed to make it work by implementing :

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("foo");

    match &s as &str {
        "foo" => {
            println!("Yes");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not understand the underlying mechanisms that make this solution the right one and why my second example does not work.

Comment: The left hand side of a match arm is a pattern. It can't include things like function calls (such as `String::from`). The literal `"foo"` is a pattern.

Comment: The reason why the last attempt works is because `String` dereferences to `str`. That is, `String`  implements the `Deref` trait with `str` as its output type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first example doesn't work, because `s` is of type `String`, which is a string variant that owns the data in it. It is matched against a string literal (which can be be used as type `&str`). match doesn't understand how to compare those two different types, so it errors.

However `String` dereferences to `&str`, by implementing `Deref<Target=str>`, which means references to `String` can be used where a `&str` is required, e.g. for comparing it to one. That's what happens in the third example. By creating the reference `&s`, the implicit deref can happen, and the two types get comparable.

You can achieve the same thing with a little less magic by using the explicit method which creates a `&str` from `String`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("foo");

    match s.as_str() {
        "foo" => {
            println!("Yes");
         },
         _ => {
             println!("No");
         }
    }
}
```

The second example tries to make things comparable making `String` the common type instead of `&str`. It doesn't work, because match expects a pattern on the left side, and not a function call which creates a new struct (and which also allocates behind the scene). Even if it would work (e.g. by moving the `String` creation outside of the match), the approach would be less desirable, because the new `String` would require a memory allocation.